# Loop 10x and Append to URL List

Tags: python, python-3.x

While trying to loop through 10 URLs, in consecutive order, I'm getting an error.  I'm trying to figure out why none of these options work.

```
page_source = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    page_source = 'https://flow.com/admin/?page=i{}'.format(i)
    page_source.append(page_source)

page_source = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    page_source = 'https://flow.com/admin/?page='.format(i)
    page_source.append(page_source)

page_source = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    page_source = 'https://flow.com/admin/?page=' + str(i)
    page_source.append(page_source)
```

All 3 throw the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I did a little research on this, and it seems like this is the way to go, but something is off here, and I'm not sure what.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Your list is named `page_source` and then your are over writing it by assigning a string value to it `page_source = 'https://airflow.com/admin/?page=i{}'.format(i)`

Comment: You define `page_source` as a list, then as a string.  It can't be both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same variable name inside your loop as you use outside, which results in the original array being overwritten by a string. Use a different variable name:

```
page_source = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    url = 'https://flow.com/admin/?page=i{}'.format(i)
    page_source.append(url)
```

Comment: OMG!  I'm so dumb!!  Face-plant!!  Ok, thanks everyone.